# Triggering a CSS animation again with a JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, css, animation, triggers

I'm trying to trigger a CSS animation again with JavaScript. Tried a lot of tricks, nothing works.

**Steps:**

1. `<canvas class="shake">` is added to `document.body`
2. `shake` animation works!
3. Press `"Shake"` button to re-add the CSS.
4. Animation **does not get triggered** again.

**Code**

https://jsbin.com/pasitic/edit?css,js,console,output

The code is really simple. I'm hoping that there is a really simple and decent solution out there. I'm using vanilla JavaScript.

**Update**

Solved and the example was updated with the working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
$btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("clicked");

  $canvas.className = "shake"; // Doesn't trigger the animation!
});

$canvas.addEventListener("animationend", function(e) {
  $canvas.className = "";
});

...
```

It adds an event listener that removes the class name which triggers after the animation ends.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove a class and add it again the animation won't play.

You could wrap the add "shake" class in a setTimeout function with a tiny delay and the animation will work.

```
$canvas.className = "";

setTimeout(function(){ 
  $canvas.className = "shake";
}, 50);
```

Also you could use the following:

```
$canvas.classList.remove("shake");
void $canvas.offsetWidth;
$canvas.classList.add("shake");
```

The `$canvas.offsetWidth;` will trigger a reflow.

You can read more about it here:
https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: Thank you for this alternative solutions. I tested the `setTimeout` solution and it works. I don't want to trigger the reflow of my canvas element, but it's good to know that trick!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the timeout with some delay worked. I have added the delay equal to `animation-duration` but adding any amount of delay will work.

```
$btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("clicked");
  $canvas.className = 'shake';
  setTimeout(function(){ $canvas.className = '';  }, 500);
});
```